# Converting points on cartesian to polar coordinates using structures, pointers, and sub-functions in c

Tags: c, function, pointers, variables

I'm supposed to convert between points on a complex plane from cartesian to polar and vice versa using pointers.

The problem is I'm trying to make subfunctions for converting between Cartesian and polar coordinates, but it seems that when the code hits the subfunctions, it can't bring the variables.

I tried debugging the code but it says variables are not available in the sub-functions.

Can someone help fix this code?
Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.141592

int c = 0;

void c2p();
void p2c();

struct complexcart
{
    double real;
    double imaginary;
} point1, point2, point3, cart_point4, cart_point5, cart_point6, *p;

struct complexpol
{
    double radius;
    double angle;
} point4, point5, point6, pol_point1, pol_point2, pol_point3, *q;

void main(){
    struct complexcart point1 = {3, 0.8};
    struct complexcart point2 = {0, log10(4)};
    struct complexcart point3 = {45.245, 0.235};

    struct complexpol point4 = {3, (PI/17)};
    struct complexpol point5 = {4, (PI/9)};
    struct complexpol point6 = {1, (PI/12)};


    while (c < 6)
    {
        if (c == 0)
        {
            struct complexcart *p = &point1;
            c2p();
            c++;
        }
        if (c == 1)
        {
            struct complexcart *p = &point2;
            c2p();
            c++;
        }
        if (c == 2)
        {
            struct complexcart *p = &point3;
            c2p();
            c++;
        }
        if (c == 3)
        {
            struct complexpol *q = &point4;
            p2c();
            c++;
        }
        if (c == 4)
        {
            struct complexpol *q = &point5;
            p2c();
            c++;
        }
        if (c == 5)
        {
            struct complexpol *q = &point6;
            p2c();
            c++;
        }
    }
    printf("Converted from cartesian to polar: \n");
    printf("%.0lf + %.1lfi -> %lf * e^(%lfi) \n", point1.real, point1.imaginary, pol_point1.radius, pol_point1.angle);
    printf("%.0lf + %lfi -> %lf * e^(%lfi) \n", point2.real, point2.imaginary, pol_point2.radius, pol_point2.angle);
    printf("%.3lf + %.3lfi -> %lf * e^(%lfi) \n", point3.real, point3.imaginary, pol_point3.radius, pol_point3.angle);

    printf("Converted from polar to cartesian: \n");
    printf("%.0lf * e^(%lfi) -> %lf + %lfi \n", point4.radius, point4.angle, cart_point4.real, cart_point4.imaginary);
    printf("%.0lf * e^(%lfi) -> %lf + %lfi \n", point5.radius, point5.angle, cart_point5.real, cart_point5.imaginary);
    printf("%.0lf * e^(%lfi) -> %lf + %lfi \n", point6.radius, point6.angle, cart_point6.real, cart_point6.imaginary);
}

void c2p(){
    if (c == 0)
    {
        p = &point1;
        struct complexpol polar_point1 = {sqrt(pow((*p).real, 2) + pow((*p).imaginary, 2)), atan((*p).imaginary/(*p).real)};
    }
    if (c == 1)
    {
        p = &point2;
        struct complexpol polar_point2 = {sqrt(pow((*p).real, 2) + pow((*p).imaginary, 2)), atan((*p).imaginary/(*p).real)};
    }
    if (c == 2)
    {
        p = &point3;
        struct complexpol polar_point3 = {sqrt(pow((*p).real, 2) + pow((*p).imaginary, 2)), atan((*p).imaginary/(*p).real)};
    }
}

void p2c(){
    if (c == 3)
    {
        q = &point4;
        struct complexcart cart_point4 = {(*q).radius * cos((*q).angle), (*q).radius * sin((*q).angle)};
    }
    if (c == 4)
    {
        q = &point5;
        struct complexcart cart_point5 = {(*q).radius * cos((*q).angle), (*q).radius * sin((*q).angle)};
    }
    if (c == 5)
    {
        q = &point6;
        struct complexcart cart_point6 = {(*q).radius * cos((*q).angle), (*q).radius * sin((*q).angle)};
    }
}
```

Comment: Too many global variables.  Your conversion functions should take a variable of an appropriate type as an argument and return a value of the other type.  The code in `p2c()` depending on the value of `c` is an abomination — the repetition appalling.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the variables again in `main` instead of using the global variables.

```
 point1 = {3, 0.8};
 point2 = {0, log10(4)};
 ...
```

This will make changes to the global variable. That will be available to the functions.

Also inside `while` loop you declare `struct complexcart *p` but it is never passed to the other functions. You wanted to make change to the global variable. That will be done

```
 p = &point1; //assignment
```

Same goes with the variables in functions (`c2p` or `p2c`) also

```
pol_point1 = {sqrt(pow((*p).real, 2) + pow((*p).imaginary, 2)), atan((*p).imaginary/(*p).real)};
```

You have declared the global variable as `pol_point1` not `polar_point1`.

Don't use global variables this much. As every function has access to it, it's hard to track the changes made by respective functions, making debugging harder.

Also your function names are not readable. Use `polarToCartesian()` or `cartesianToPolar()` to make the code readable.